# How can I read Scrapy Start_urls from MySql database?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am trying to read and write all output from Mysql. When My spiders start scraping I want to get all URL from MySQL database so I try to make a function to read data.

**readdata.py:**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

def dataReader(marketName):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                            database='test',
                                            user='root',
                                            port=3306,
                                            password='1234')
        sql_select_Query = "SELECT shop_URL FROM datatable.bot_markets WHERE shop_name='"+marketName+"';"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        return records
    except Error as e:
        print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            connection.close()
            cursor.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I want to call the this function from my spider as follow.

***My Spider:***

```
import scrapy
import re
import mysql.connector

from ..items import FirstBotItem
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from first_bot.readdata import dataReader

class My_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "My_Spider"
   allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com/"]
   start_urls = dataReader(name)
   
   def parse(self, response):
       location = "quotes"
       for product in response.xpath('.//div[@class="product-card product-action "]'):
           
           product_link = response.url
           prices = product.xpath('.//div[@class="price-tag"]/span[@class="value"]/text()').get()
           if prices != None:prices = re.sub(r"[\s]", "", prices)
           title = product.xpath('.//h5[@class="title product-card-title"]/a/text()').get()
           unit = product.xpath('.//div[@class="select single-select"]//i/text()').get()
           if unit != None: unit = re.sub(r"[\s]", "", unit)
           item = FirstBotItem()
           item['LOKASYON'] = location
           item['YEAR'] = 2020
           item['MONTH'] = 8
           yield item
```

I am doing something wrong with start_urls but I couldn't figure out. I am getting this error.

```
_set_url
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got tuple:
2020-08-24 15:46:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

My main task is to get all URLs from the database. Because someone will write the URL on the same website and the spider will crawl automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `return list(records)` instead of `return records` in dataReader function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the logic in `dataReader` method from:

```
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    return records
```

to :

```
records = cursor.fetchall()
records_list = []
for rec in records:
    records_list.append(rec)
return records_list
```

Comment: When I check the type of ***records*** before return it returns <class 'list'>